# Android unit test fails in debug, passes otherwise

Tags: android, database, debugging, junit, android-contentprovider

I have an app which uses a sqlite database and a ContentProvider to serve up data. The eclipse project has a unit test which adds a record to a database, retrieves it and asserts against the retrieved data:

```
    public void testAddNewVehicle()
{
    Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle("xyz", "my car", 111f);
    long result = VehicleProvider.addVehicle(getContext(), vehicle1);

    assertTrue(1 == result);

    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = VehicleProvider.getVehicles(getContext());

    assertEquals(1, vehicles.size());
    assertEquals("xyz", vehicles.get(0).getRegistrationNo());
    assertEquals("my car", vehicles.get(0).getDescription());
    assertEquals(111.0f, vehicles.get(0).getInitialMileage());
}
```

My setup method deletes the database:

```
    @Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    deleteTestDatabase();
}
```

The test passes when I choose 'run', but if I choose debug, it fails at the `assertEquals(1, vehicles.size());` line. After stepping through the code I have noticed something strange: even though the data insertion succeeds and `assertTrue(1 == result);` passes, the database does not exist on the file system at this point. It is only created when `VehicleProvider.getVehicles(getContext());` is called.

Both addVehicle() and getVehicles() result in a call to `getWritableDatabase()`, so I don't see why the first call does not create the database on disk. The addVehicle() method will eventually call insert() (irrelevant code omitted):

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
{
    String table = table = Constants.VEHICLE_TABLE_NAME;

    long rowID = UKMPGDataProvider.getWritableDatabase().insert(table, null, values);

    // ---if added successfully---
    if (rowID > 0)
    {
        Uri insertedRowUri = insertedRowUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(VEHICLE_CONTENT_URI, rowID);

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedRowUri, null);
        return insertedRowUri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}
```

And the getVehicle() will eventually call query():

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqlBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.setTables(uri.getPathSegments().get(0));

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == VEHICLE_ID)
        // ---if getting a particular vehicle
        sqlBuilder.appendWhere(BaseColumns._ID + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));

    if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "")
    {
        sortOrder = BaseColumns._ID;
    }

    Cursor c = sqlBuilder.query(UKMPGDataProvider.getWritableDatabase(), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    // ---register to watch a content URI for changes---
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
```

As I say, the test passes when not in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I found out what was happening, even if I don't fully understand it.

In the `onCreate()` in my `ContentProvider`, I was leaving the database open:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    UKMPGDataProvider.init(getContext(), Constants.DATABASE_NAME);
    return (UKMPGDataProvider.getWritableDatabase() == null) ? false : true;
}
```

(In my defence, this was copied from a tutorial on the net.)

In my test, the `addVehicle()` would result in a call the `getWriteableDatabase()` on `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which looks like this (shortened for clarity):

```
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen() && !mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
        return mDatabase;  // The database is already open for business
    }

        //lots more initialisation here, omitted
        int version = db.getVersion();
        if (version != mNewVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (version == 0) {
                    //DATABASE CREATED HERE
                    onCreate(db);
                    //END
                } else {
                    onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                }
                db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    //omitted code again
}
```

As I had left the database open, execution would not get passed the first `if` statement and the `onCreate(db)` line would never be reached.

In my code, I would close the database after inserting a vehicle, so next call to `getWriteableDatabase()` (getVehicles()) would get passed the first `if` statement and execute the `onCreate(db)`.

It doesn't really explain why the first insertion was successful though. And it doesn't explain why the test passed in 'run' mode. I added some logging to the `onCreate()` in my `ContentProvider` and `SQLiteOpenHelper` and in run mode the `ContentProvider` `onCreate()` is called twice.

I don't know if this made the difference or not...